# Exception Handling In Android Unit Test Case

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, exception, junit

I am doing Android Unit Test Case Execution and for Negative Test Case I should get exception, but for some API's Exception is not caught.

Please do find the example below:

```
public void testInsertSenderType_n()  {
        DBSms obj = new DBSms(getContext());
        obj.open();

        int i =0;
        int a =0;
        boolean result = true;

        i=obj.GetToatlCount();
        obj.insertSmsText(i+1,"Hello to testInsertSenderType_n");
        a=obj.TotalcountSms("Inbox");
        try 
        {
            obj.insertSenderType(-100, "Richard", "Inbox", 0);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            result = false;


    }
        assertEquals(a,obj.TotalcountSms("Inbox"));
        assertEquals(false,result);
        obj.close();
    }
```

Here in, `obj.insertSenderType(-100, "Richard", "Inbox", 0);` should throw an exception. But it is not thrown.

Please do guide where can I be Wrong.

Comment: So, the method should throw an exception, and the unit test shows that it's not the case, is that right? If so, congratulations: you've just discovered a bug in the code of DBSms thanks to your unit tests. Fix it and check that the unit test passes once the fix is applied.

Answer (score 1):

I use following method to expect proper exception:

```
try {
   doSomethingToProvokeException();

   fail("there ought to be an exception dude, but was not");
} catch(ExeptionIHaveProvoked ex) {
   doAssertionnsonThrowsException
}
```

You do not need variables to keeps exception state.   As for why no exception is thrown in your code - nobody cann tell it to you, unless you provide  source of object.